# Check if object in stream is an observable

Tags: javascript, stream, system.reactive

I would like to check if the object returnet from the forEach method in the objectStream is an observer, I tried with the typeof but apparently is not working, please find below the snippet:

```js
var Observable = Rx.Observable;

var button = document.getElementById('button');
var click$ = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

click$.forEach(function(item){
  
  console.log('clicked', typeof(item), item instanceof Rx.Observable );
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button">click me</button>  
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

T

Comment: Why would you expect an observer instead of a value?

Comment: foreach is reaturning a type of the same object that called the method

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is creating an observable stream of `MouseEvent` instances.

It would be highly unusual to generate a stream of observers. If that genuinely is your scenario, it would be helpful if the snippet reflected that.

Comment: Does the OP mean Observer (from question) or Observable (from the title)? A sequence of sequences is not an unusual thing (i.e. to use `Switch`/`Concat`/`Merge`)

Comment: All true, lets see what clarification of the scenario yields!

Comment: this is a common scenario for reactive programming, a foreach should be returning a stream of the same type as the object.

Comment: Hmm... it's not really clear what you are asking then. Your foreach is iterating over a stream of the expected type (a stream of `MouseEvent`). It won't be (in this case), an "observer" (subscriber to a stream) or an "observable" (a stream that can be observed) - rather you can call it an "observed value". It's not at all clear (from your example) why you are checking it for a type of `Observable`. Your values are going to be `MouseEvent`.